# JSLint: unexpected end

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

```
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
    "use strict";

    return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
}
```

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) complains and says this:

```
Unexpected '(end)'.
}
line 5 character 1
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's a function expression (not a function declaration), it should end with a semi-colon:

```
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
    "use strict";

    return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
}; //<-- Semi-colon here
```

JSLint complains about an "unexpected end" because it didn't expect to encounter the end of its input at the closing `}` character.